# Mkpasswd equivlent command in RHEL

Tags: linux, rhel

I need an equivalent command to mkpasswd to use it in rhel ,i searched a lot but no use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should install the [`expect`](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/expect-5.45-14.el7_1.x86_64.rpm.html) package which provide the `mkpasswd` command:

```
# yum install expect
```

Comment: This answer, although technically correct, might not be doing what you expect (pun intended). You are likely looking for the `mkpasswd` provided by the `whois` package, which is completely different to the one in `expect`. If so, you'll be disappointed to know that it's not available until EL9. See [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2054043). In fact it's added so recently that it might not yet be available at time of writing. So if you intend to generate a hashed password, you may wish to use the solution [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/221403).

Comment: you like linking to paywalls ? :/